# javascript cannot find a method which exists

Tags: javascript

I have a pretty simple function declared in my **JavaScript** file, which is just supposed to return whether or not the validation has begun:

```
window.Validator = function(){
    this._started = false;
    this.started = function(){
        return this._started;
    };
}

Validator.started();
```

However, when I call `Validator.started()`, even though it's literally directly after the declaration, it will throw the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Validator.started is not a function

Really scratching my head with this one and have no idea why it isn't working.

Answer (score 7):

You should create an instance of your Validator

```
new Validator().started()
```

Comment: Oh. My. God. I can't believe I didn't realise this. Thank you mate - much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a context. Or simply, it is an object which is on the left of dot. For example:

```
let v = new Validator();
v.started(); // v will be 'this' in your method
```

Your code:

```
Validator.started();
```

It means, that `started()` is a **static** method of `Validator` (method of exactly function `Validator()`). You have to write code as I write above. Or:

```
window.Validator = function() {};
Validator._started = false;
Validator.started = function() {
    return this._started;
};
console.log(Validator.started());
```

Here `_started` is a static property and `started()` is a static method of `Validator()`.

Answer (score 0):

`this` in a function without 'use strict' points to the global object, that is `window`.

So your `this.started = function(){...}` is defined on the `window` object. Of course, it is only defined after the `Validator` is called.

So this code works, though it may not how you want to use it.

```
window.Validator = function(){
    this._started = false;
    this.started = function(){
        return this._started;
    };
}

Validator();
started();
console.log(_started);
```

If you do use 'use strict', `this` is `undefined` in the function definition area. You need to create an Object of `Validator`, `this` would be the object when you call the method.

Comment: I am using `"use strict";`.